# Java javax.crypto and PHP openssl_decrypt is not identical

Tags: java, php, encryption, cryptography

I'm porting java decrypter code to PHP.
I have 3 files:

- encrypted.data - it's encrypted data with AES/CBC/NoPadding(128)
  algo.
- aes.key - it's secret key.
- initialization.vector - it's initialization vector

see here at [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11f1b20510f4205bec655230ce9c5608)

I use in Java javax.crypto package use AES/CBC/NoPadding (128) algorithm for decrypted data. In PHP i use openssl extensions

PHP Version 7.1.0
PHP info (openssl):

- OpenSSL Library Version  LibreSSL 2.4.4
- OpenSSL Header Version   LibreSSL 2.4.4

My examples of code:

My Java code:

```java
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        File AesKeyFile = new File("./Cipher2PHP/aes.key");
        File InitializationVectorFile = new File("./Cipher2PHP/initialization.vector");
        File EncryptedDataFile = new File("./Cipher2PHP/encrypted.data");
        byte[] AesKeyData = Files.readAllBytes(AesKeyFile.toPath());
        byte[] InitializationVectorData = Files.readAllBytes(InitializationVectorFile.toPath());
        byte[] EncryptedData = Files.readAllBytes(EncryptedDataFile.toPath());

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(AesKeyData, "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, new IvParameterSpec(InitializationVectorData));

        byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(EncryptedData);
        String decrypted = new String(result);

        System.out.printf("Your data: %s\n", decrypted);
    }
}
```

My portable PHP code

```php
<?php
$AesKeyData = file_get_contents('./Cipher2PHP/aes.key');
$InitializationVectorData = file_get_contents('./Cipher2PHP/initialization.vector');
$EncryptedData = file_get_contents('./Cipher2PHP/encrypted.data');
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt(
    $EncryptedData,
    'AES-128-CBC',
    $AesKeyData,
    OPENSSL_NO_PADDING,
    $InitializationVectorData
);
printf("Your data: %s\n", $decrypted);
```

Java code works as needed. PHP code works with mismatch.

Java code output:

```
Your data: My very secure data. Very secure
Process finished with exit code 0
```

PHP code output:

```
Your data: �j��2��䈤�n�h�/sEH�,/-��-�^[
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Base64 encoded datas:

PHP:

```
Base64 AES Key:                 "Kl/LF5HSL7YCRbPYNp7QssJzcVY/vx88nt9rEYJaXQo="
Base64 InitializationVector:    "QXF/8HO4te38LhhuFP9+hA=="
Base64 EncryptedData:           "eA1w+ysqsHIdaXsQRSgt9nLPDj7ILcqyZdCW3wDBcy0="
Decrypted Result:               "xmqJ0TKgx+SIpP1u/hNoyS9zRUjEAAEsLy251S2hXls="
```

Java:

```
Base64 AES Key:                 "Kl/LF5HSL7YCRbPYNp7QssJzcVY/vx88nt9rEYJaXQo="
Base64 InitializationVector:    "QXF/8HO4te38LhhuFP9+hA=="
Base64 EncryptedData:           "eA1w+ysqsHIdaXsQRSgt9nLPDj7ILcqyZdCW3wDBcy0="
Decrypted Result:               "TXkgdmVyeSBzZWN1cmUgZGF0YS4gVmVyeSBzZWN1cmU="
```

Files in console:

```
./Cipher2PHP mac$ file -I *
aes.key:               application/octet-stream; charset=binary
initialization.vector: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
encrypted.data:        application/octet-stream; charset=binary
./Cipher2PHP mac$ xxd  aes.key 
0000000: 2a5f cb17 91d2 2fb6 0245 b3d8 369e d0b2  *_..../..E..6...
0000010: c273 7156 3fbf 1f3c 9edf 6b11 825a 5d0a  .sqV?..<..k..Z].
./Cipher2PHP mac$ xxd  initialization.vector 
0000000: 4171 7ff0 73b8 b5ed fc2e 186e 14ff 7e84  Aq..s......n..~.
./Cipher2PHP mac$ xxd  encrypted.data 
0000000: 780d 70fb 2b2a b072 1d69 7b10 4528 2df6  x.p.+*.r.i{.E(-.
0000010: 72cf 0e3e c82d cab2 65d0 96df 00c1 732d  r..>.-..e.....s-
./Cipher2PHP mac$ xxd -b aes.key 
0000000: 00101010 01011111 11001011 00010111 10010001 11010010  *_....
0000006: 00101111 10110110 00000010 01000101 10110011 11011000  /..E..
000000c: 00110110 10011110 11010000 10110010 11000010 01110011  6....s
0000012: 01110001 01010110 00111111 10111111 00011111 00111100  qV?..<
0000018: 10011110 11011111 01101011 00010001 10000010 01011010  ..k..Z
000001e: 01011101 00001010                                      ].
./Cipher2PHP mac$ xxd -b initialization.vector 
0000000: 01000001 01110001 01111111 11110000 01110011 10111000  Aq..s.
0000006: 10110101 11101101 11111100 00101110 00011000 01101110  .....n
000000c: 00010100 11111111 01111110 10000100                    ..~.
./Cipher2PHP mac$ xxd -b encrypted.data 
0000000: 01111000 00001101 01110000 11111011 00101011 00101010  x.p.+*
0000006: 10110000 01110010 00011101 01101001 01111011 00010000  .r.i{.
000000c: 01000101 00101000 00101101 11110110 01110010 11001111  E(-.r.
0000012: 00001110 00111110 11001000 00101101 11001010 10110010  .>.-..
0000018: 01100101 11010000 10010110 11011111 00000000 11000001  e.....
000001e: 01110011 00101101
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of both? What format is your IV/Key in?  Try printing the result as base64 in both rather than converting to a string in Java.  Binary data and strings don't make a happy cryptographer.

Comment: Yeah, which one provides the output you expect? The input (keys, iv, cryptogram/ciphertext) would be helpful as well. Otherwise we'll have to close this as off topic as we cannot identify the right code.

Comment: i added base64 datas.

Comment: Java code works as needed. PHP code works with mismatch.
i print output of both in question.

Comment: If use mcrypt library in php - 
`$decryptedWithMcryptLibrary = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $AesKeyData, $EncryptedData, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $InitializationVectorData);` Then everything works correctly. The string is decrypted correctly. But mcrypt library is deprecated in PHP 7.x... I want use openssl library in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, the version of AES to use (128, 192 or 256 bits) is determined by the length of the key you provide, which must be exactly one of those lengths.

In PHP you explicitly specify the version of AES to use in the method argument to `openssl_decrypt` or `openssl_encrypt`, e.g. “aes-128-cbc”. PHP will then either truncate or extend with zero bytes the key you provide so that it is the required length.

You are using a 32 byte (256 bit) key, so your Java code is using AES-256. However your PHP code specifies 'AES-128-CBC', so you are using different versions.

To get the PHP version to behave like the Java version, change the method string in the call to `openssl_decrypt` to `'aes-256-cbc'`.

To get the Java version to behave like the PHP version (I don’t think you want to do this, but I include it for completeness), copy the first 16 bytes of the key and only use them when creating the `SecretKeySpec` object.

Comment: Thanx! Yes, my key 256 bytes! And java use AES 256 CBC algo, i'm stupid...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I tried lots of possibilities in code but not worked .But using this solution code Works Perfectly.Thank you so much @matt.